# How to find value between commas

Tags: php, regex

i need to find regex which selects data look like 
987 0000 ASDS CT 2017-11-14,11.34.24 ASD SADASD  
and 87 0001 ASDA CT 2017-11-14 11.35.24 ASD DASDAS 

at two strings 

987   ,0000,ASDS,CT,2017-11-14,11.34.24,ASD  ,SADASD 

987   ,0001,ASDA,CT,2017-11-14,11.35.24,ASD  ,DASDAS

How do I select data without commas? Thank you.

Comment: _i need to find regex at 2 string like..._ What is your expected output? And pls format your question properly

Comment: If you want to use another approach instead of regexp, you could try to use explode() to convert the strings to arrays and then use array_diff() to search for the differences.

Comment: [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) could be a starting point; then implode on a space

Comment: I am still not sure I understand what you want to do but could it be that you can replace (str_replace()) the comma character with a blank resulting in you actually removing all the commas from the string?
Have a look at this on how to write a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will also provide the result what you want

```
$string1= '987 ,0000,ASDS,CT,2017-11-14,11.34.24,ASD ,SADASD';
$expl = explode(',',$string1);   
$new_val_string1 = '';

foreach($expl as $val){       
   $new_val_string1 .= trim($val).' '; 
}
echo  $new_val_string1;
```